# How to tell asp.net mvc and api to deserialize model with private setter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Lets say I got something like

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; private set; }
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult Test(TestMoel model)
{
    ....
}
```

then navigate to

```
/Test?a=1&b=2
```

only property a will be set. property b is ignored due to private setter.

Is there a way to tell the serializer to deserialize properties with a private setter? (both MVC and web api)

Is there any downside for doing so?

Comment: By default, ASP.Net MVC uses http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx whereas Web API uses NewtonSoft JSON.Net.  So unless you add custom code to MVC to change the default serializer, you couldn't bring the two into alignment anyways.  That said, you'd still have the issue of serializing to private setters which is typically an anti-pattern.  Can it be done?  Sure.  Should it be?  Probably not.

Comment: In short, you can't deserialize into a private setter. You could ignore that property or properties and set them some other way after the fact, but obviously, if the setter is not public something like a deserializer can't set it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt that's not ***technically*** true.  You can write custom converters and use reflection to set those types, although it certainly isn't recommended.

Comment: @DavidL can you elaborate more on why it is an anti pattern?

Comment: Accessor levels are there to specifically provide encapsulation and clear API boundaries.  You are violating these boundaries if you attempt to work around them.  Private setters are NOT supposed to be set from a public context, which is exactly what deserialization is.  So yes, you can make it work, but it violates the intrinsic contract of the code itself.

Comment: @DavidL The model's values should only be set by serialization or in the constructor. They should not be changed by code so that is why I want to make them private. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: i am afraid you must write your own ContractResolver to make it work. My suggestion is to create viewmodel for this purpose

Comment: @DavidL: Okay, perhaps it's better said under normal circumstances you can't deserialize into a private setter. Taking such herculean steps to try to get around the accessor level begs the question of having the access level. Either it should be public or there's a reason it's private, and skirting around that is going to bork your app.

Comment: @Steve my recommendation would be to not mix concerns.  Have a publicly available deserialization model and map it to a model with private setters.  This way each model represents a type of functionality within the app and the lines aren't blurred.  It is more overhead yes, but it is clear and intentional.  Otherwise, relax your private setter restriction and trust your developers to write wise code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I agree 100% (which is why I haven't posted an answer showing such a thing) :).  I just merely wanted to point out that it is indeed possible.

Comment: @DavidL do you want to type out an answer for that. I will accept it

Comment: @Steve sure thing, done.  Please let me know if it isn't the level of detail you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is theoretically possible to write a custom converter that utilizes reflection to map to private setter properties, it is not recommended.

Rather, it is preferential to maintain clear, consistent API boundaries by respecting property accessor levels.

One way to achieve this is by utilizing different models to achieve different goals.  Create a simple POCO with all public setters that is used as your deserialization model.  Map that model to a second model with private setters that is used throughout your application.  This allows you to achieve proper separation of concerns within your app.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in one comment, you should not deserialize over a private property (why is it private in the first place?). One way is to use a wrapper property:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; private set; }

    public int bSet 
    {
        set { b = value; }
    }
}
```

But the URL must be changed:

```
/Test?a=1&bSet=2
```